# Maximum call stack size exceeded when I try to create two documents that contain references to each other

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Below are my Schemas for post and reply.(simplified version)

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    replies:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Reply"}]
});

const ReplySchema = new Schema({
    post: {
        type:Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:"Post"
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
    }
});
```

When I try to create and save the two objects that have references to each other. I am getting the error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
let post = new Post({
    'title':postData.title
});

let reply = new Reply({
    'post': post,
    'message':postData.message
});

post.replies.push(reply);

post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err) return next(err);
    reply.save(function(err,reply){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.status(201).json({'success':1});
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just saw a similar question on this site. And the problem is when we want to pass a document as a ref property of another document. We have to use doc._id, instead of the doc itself.

So here, we should not pass post directly:

```
let reply = new Reply({
    'post': post,
    'message':postData.message
});
```

Need to change to:

```
let reply = new Reply({
    'post': post._id,
    'message':postData.message
});
```